# How to change paths of multiple hyperlink files in excel?

Tags: excel, hyperlink, filepath

I want to change the paths of multiple hyperlink files in excel at once.

Most of them are `file:///F:\URL PDF\"name of file"`

I want to change the path to `file:///C:\USER\Christina\Desktop\PDFs\URL PDF\"name of file"`.

Note that each "name of file" for every file is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with VBA.

Each Worksheet has a Hyperlinks Collection. Each Hyperlink has a property named "Address". Those addresses are strings. For strings there is a function Replace(). This function can replace one substring with another.

Example for Worksheet 1 in ActiveWorkbook:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
 For Each oHyperlink In .Hyperlinks
  MsgBox oHyperlink.Address
  sNewAddress = Replace(Expression:=oHyperlink.Address, Find:="F:\URL PDF\", Replace:="C:\USER\Christina\Desktop\PDFs\URL PDF\")
  oHyperlink.Address = sNewAddress
  MsgBox oHyperlink.Address
 Next
End With
```

Greetings

Axel

Comment: Thank you my friend  - this proved very useful when someone had messed up our sharepoint pages